How do I get alt codes to work in PuTTY?
I want to use decimal alt codes, e.g. just 0..255, with PuTTY. I don't need hexadecimal or large-value unicode code points — just bytes. I can enter them with no problem in Terminal, including to a short C program where I can verify the correct decimal values. I can enter alt{192} and see that it's really 192. All good so far. (I am using enclosing braces here to represent holding down alt while entering digits on the numeric pad with num lock on.)
When I try the same thing in PuTTY (version 0.81), I get nothing. Not even the wrong thing — nothing. I can test it with alt{111} which should simply give a lower case "o". Nothing is sent or echoed. I have tried changing the translation from UTF-8 to Win1252 with no effect. That shouldn't matter anyway, since "o" will translate to "o" no matter what the translation is. I have also tried preceding the digits with a zero, i.e. alt{0111}, but still no joy.
I am confused as to how the application can even know that alt{111} was entered, as opposed to "o". Shouldn't the application see exactly the same thing in both cases? How is PuTTY able to behave differently from Terminal?
I tried Notepad, and it too gets nothing at all from alt codes.
What is going on here?

alt+1,1,1 gets me o in PuTTY (also Windows 11).

@MartinPrikryl I presume that you are not entering any plus signs or commas, correct?

@MartinPrikryl What about Notepad for you?

Sure, no pluses or commas. Works in Notepad too.
